# Questions about some sentences

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

I met some sentences in *Lingua Latin per se Illustrata: Roma Aeterna* that I can hardly understand:

> Hīc Aenēās genitōrem Anchīsēn āmīsit, ille enim **cōnfectus** aetāte ē vītā excessit — nēquīquam ex tantīs perīculīs ēreptus. (Ch. 38, L. 210)

"Here Aeneas lost his father Anchises, because he *(who was completed?)* died for age — taken away from so many dangers in vain." What does ***cōnfectus*** actually mean?

> Hanc urbem *(=Karthāginem)* Jūnō magis aliīs omnibus dīlēxisse dīcitur, hoc rēgnum omnium gentium esse volēbat. (Ch. 39, L. 3)

"It is said that Juno greatly preferred this city to all the others, ..." Is ***hoc rēgnum*** nominative or accusative? *Who* wanted to be *what*?

> Sed audīverat genus ā Trōiānō sanguine ortum ōlim arcem Karthāginis expugnātūrum esse. (Ch. 39, L. 5)

"But she *(=Juno?)* had heard(?) that a/the tribe (?) that rose from the Trojans' blood would once conquer the stronghold of Karthago.", is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What does cōnfectus actually mean?**

[According to Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dconficio), a common meaning of *conficere* is "to diminish, lessen, weaken an object; to sweep away, destroy, kill, wear out, consume." In particular, they mention: "In part. perf.: sicut fortis equus... senio confectu' quiescit, impaired, weakened, Enn. ap. Cic. Sen. 5, 14; and so very freq.: confectus senectute, Cic. Rab. Perd. 7, 21: aetate, Sall. J. 9, 4" etc. So I would translate this as: "he died, weakened by his age/worn out by the years" or so.

**Is hoc rēgnum nominative or accusative?**

It is an accusative, part of an AcI construction that depends on *volebat*, the subject of which I guess is *Juno*: she wanted this kingdom to belong to all peoples/to all the world.

Your translation of the third sentence looks good to me.